# Return Most Recent Record group by 2 ID fields

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to display the current status of a part ('approved' or 'not approved')
I am setting up the status table as MaterialNo, ToolID, Status, Asofdate

the idea is I may have several tools approved and several not approved. I want to be able to see the most recent status for each tool but I don't want to see the historical status.

have tried to use MAX(Asofdate) and group by MaterialNo, ToolID, and Status but it returns all of the status history for each.

```
SELECT MaterialNo, ToolID, PPAPStatus, MAX(Asof) as "AsOf"
  FROM [MfgDataCollector].[dbo].[PPAPStatus]
  Group By MaterialNo, ToolID, PPAPStatus
```

The Status Table has this data:

```
MaterialNo  ToolID  Status          Asofdate
52748677    1       Not approved 2019-10-10
52748677    1       approved    2019-10-13
52748677    2       approved    2019-10-14
```

I Want to see:

```
MaterialNo  ToolID  Status         Asofdate
52748677    1       approved    2019-10-13
52748677    2       approved    2019-10-14
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One solution that usually has very good performance is a correlated subquery:

```
select p.*
from [MfgDataCollector].[dbo].[PPAPStatus] p
where p.asof = (select max(p2.asof)
                from [MfgDataCollector].[dbo].[PPAPStatus] p2
                where p2.MaterialNo = p.MaterialNo and
                      p2.ToolID = p.ToolID
               );
```

For optimal performance, you want an index on `(MaterialNo, ToolID, asof)`.

Comment: My project got put on the far far back burner for a while but since im not busy with other parts of my job I finally got back to it and this worked great!

Answer (score 3):

I like using `ROW_NUMBER` with a `TOP 1 WITH TIES` trick here:

```
SELECT TOP 1 WITH TIES MaterialNo, ToolID, Status, Asofdate
FROM [MfgDataCollector].[dbo].[PPAPStatus]
ORDER BY ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY MaterialNo, ToolID ORDER BY Asofdate DESC);
```

Comment: with rownumber() itself i guess for duplicates as well different nos would be assigned

Comment: @HimanshuAhuja Yes...this answer is not suitable if the OP wants to retain ties for each material/tool combination.  Then, your approach, using `RANK`, would be one valid way to proceed.

Comment: Yeah.., rank() is one of the valid method in that case

Answer (score 2):

Best option would be row_number()

```
   Select MaterialNo, ToolID, 
    PPAPStatus,AsofNow from (Select 
     MaterialNo, ToolID, 
      PPAPStatus,AsofNow, row_number() 
       over 
           (partition 
         by MaterialNo, ToolId, PPAStatus 
              order by 
            AsofNow desc) rn
       FROM [MfgDataCollector].[dbo]. 
       [PPAPStatus]
      ) t where t.rn=1
```

Comment: . . I'm not sure how you define "best".  Often a correlated subquery has better performance.

Comment: Ummm.. the reason I called it best coz a corelated subquery backtracks during its run hence it would take more time in case of huge set of records

Comment: . . I have no idea what you are trying to say.  A correlated subquery with the correct index is often the fastest method for such queries.

Comment: I mean to say the corelated subquery reexecutes with each outer row as per the condition specified but are you sure the partitioning as per the above query with correct index would take more execution time as that of corelated subquery.

Answer (score 0):

Best option would be **ROW_NUMBER()** with no more complex logic with easy partition by fields.

Please find below query for as of requirement.

```
;WITH CTE AS
(
SELECT *, 
ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY MaterialNo,ToolID ORDER BY Asofdate DESC) AS ROWNM
FROM [MfgDataCollector].[dbo].[PPAPStatus]
)
SELECT * FROM CTE WHERE ROWNM=1
```